# Getting initial quaternion for a rigid body

Tags: rotation, orientation, quaternions

I have a rigid body whose centre of mass is located at position **p** relative to origin of fixed global reference frame. **ux**,**uy** and **uz** are three orthogonal unit vectors relative to origin of the fixed global reference frame. These unit vectors represent the local coordinate frame of the rigid body. The local coordinate frame follows linear and rotational motion of the rigid body.

How can I build an initial quaternion for this rigid body in its current orientation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"ux,uy and uz are three orthogonal unit vectors relative to origin of the fixed global reference frame."

It is exactly the 3x3 rotation matrix. You can just convert from this 3x3 matrix to quaternion, using good known implementation.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot for answer. I also got to the same answer : convert rotation matrix made up of these orthogonal unit vectors to quaternion.

Comment: One additional question. I now that if I now want to map a point on rigid body with position vector V to the local coordinate system based on rotation matrix B, I can accomplish this by doing this: Vnew = Transpose(B).V. Now instead I want to do the same using my quaternion q= MatrixToQuaternion(B),  should I do something like this, Vnew = q^(-1) . V . q  ?

Comment: Quaternion with inverse rotation can be obtained just inverting vector (x,y,z) OR scalar (w) part of quaternion.